# How to use glossary contextetual filter?

Tags: 7, views

I created a user type view and add a contextual filter of User:Name. I enabled the glossary mod add character limit to 1. Same setting as glossary view. But still it not showing the filter (A|B|C). Am I missing any setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Adding a Attachment Display to views.